# Check if value is in array of values in r dataframe

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with two columns `Fruits` and `Groups` . I want to check if the value in `Fruits` is the array in `Groups`. If yes then mutate a new field and add yes or no.

```
df <- data.frame(Fruits = c("Apple","Banana","Orange","Kiwi"),
                 Group = I(list(c("Apple","Strawberry"), 
                                c("Orange","Kiwi"),
                                c("Apple","Banana"),
                                c("Apple","Kiwi")
                                )))

df$Fruits %in% df$Group
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As `Group` is a list we can't directly compare it. One way is to use `mapply`

```
df$Present <- c("No", "Yes")[mapply(`%in%`, df$Fruits, df$Group) + 1]

df
#  Fruits        Group Present
#1  Apple Apple, S....     Yes
#2 Banana Orange, Kiwi      No
#3 Orange Apple, B....      No
#4   Kiwi  Apple, Kiwi     Yes
```

`mapply` returns `TRUE`/`FALSE` values and then we use indexing technique to get `Yes`/`No`.

```
mapply(`%in%`, df$Fruits, df$Group)
#[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

---

Or similarly with `purrr` `map2_lgl`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df %>%
  mutate(Present = c("No", "Yes")[map2_lgl(Fruits, Group, `%in%`) + 1])
```

Comment: Thank you. Instead of yes no  how do I  add that value from Fruit column

Comment: @SNT In that case, since it can return empty values you can do something like `mapply(function(x, y) ifelse(x %in% y, intersect(x, y), ""), df$Fruits, df$Group)`

Comment: I have the data in different format . Can I add it to existing question here.

Comment: I just added it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55662064/mutate-new-column-if-value-from-one-column-matches-from-a-column-with-array-of-v

Answer (score 0):

We can use

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, Present := unlist(Map(`%in%`, Fruits, Group))]
```