# Mutate new column if value from one column matches from a column with array of values

Tags: r

I have two columns. I want add a new column with value yes or no based on if the value from `Country` is present in the array of values in `Major teams`.

Select `Country` from `Major teams`

```
tibble::tribble(
    ~COUNTRY,                                                                                    ~Major.teams,
  "Zimbabwe",             "['Zimbabwe,', 'Zimbabwe Under-13s,', 'Zimbabwe Under-18s,', 'Zimbabwe Under-19s']",
  "Zimbabwe",                                          "['Zimbabwe,', 'Mountaineers,', 'Zimbabwe Under-19s']",
  "Zimbabwe",                                                           "['Zimbabwe,', 'Zimbabwe Under-19s']",
  "Zimbabwe",                                    "['Zimbabwe,', 'Zimbabwe Under-17s,', 'Zimbabwe Under-19s']",
  "Zimbabwe",                                                                   "['Zimbabwe,', 'Shropshire']",
  "Zimbabwe",                        "['Zimbabwe,', 'Mountaineers,', 'Zimbabwe Cubs,', 'Zimbabwe Under-19s']",
  "Zimbabwe",                                                           "['Zimbabwe,', 'Zimbabwe Under-19s']",
  "Zimbabwe",                                    "['Zimbabwe Women,', 'Mountaineers,', 'Zimbabwe Under-19s']",
  "Zimbabwe",             "['Zimbabwe,', 'Zimbabwe Under-13s,', 'Zimbabwe Under-17s,', 'Zimbabwe Under-19s']",
  "Zimbabwe",                                                            "['Zimbabwe,', 'Natal,', 'Suffolk']",
  "Zimbabwe",                                                            "['Zimbabwe,', 'Western Transvaal']",
  "Zimbabwe",                                    "['Zimbabwe,', 'Zimbabwe Under-17s,', 'Zimbabwe Under-19s']",
  "Zimbabwe",                                                                    "['Zimbabwe,', 'Southerns']",
  "Zimbabwe",           "['Zimbabwe,', 'Mountaineers,', 'Zimbabwe A,', 'Zimbabwe Under-19s,', 'Zimbabwe XI']",
   "England",                                                     "['Zimbabwe-Rhodesia,', 'Kent,', 'Surrey']"
  )
```

Comment: do you want to match it fixed or just pattern? What would be the expected output for this? Would "Zimbabwe" and "Zimbabwe Women" match in 8th row?

Comment: I would like to match `Zimbabwe`.In that case `Zimbabwe Women` should not be a match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `Major.teams` is a single string value and not list of values we need to do some cleaning for this.

We remove opening and closing square brackets and apostrophe (`[|]|'`) from the `Major.teams` column and then split the string on comma (`,`) and return `Yes` only if `any` of the value matches exactly to `Country` column.

```
c("No", "Yes")[mapply(function(x, y) any(x == y), 
     df$COUNTRY, strsplit(gsub("\\[|'|\\]", "", df$Major.teams), ",")) + 1] 

# [1] "Yes" "Yes" "Yes" "Yes" "Yes" "Yes" "Yes" "No"  "Yes" "Yes" "Yes" "Yes" 
#     "Yes" "Yes" "No"
```

---

If we want the values which match we can use `ifelse`

```
as.character(ifelse(mapply(function(x, y) any(x == y), 
df$COUNTRY, strsplit(gsub("\\[|'|\\]", "", df$Major.teams), ",")), df$COUNTRY, ""))

#[1] "Zimbabwe" "Zimbabwe" "Zimbabwe" "Zimbabwe" "Zimbabwe" "Zimbabwe" "Zimbabwe" 
#    ""   "Zimbabwe" "Zimbabwe" "Zimbabwe" "Zimbabwe" "Zimbabwe" "Zimbabwe" ""
```